# How to print symbols vertically in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, symbols, wing-ide

I just want to print a symbol a certain amount of times vertically.

```
def draw_symbol():
        print()
        symbol = ""
        for num in range(8):
            symbol += "*"        
        print(symbol)
        return

    draw_row()
```

The output is  "*******"  but it is supposed to be vertical.

Comment: Put newline characters between each symbol?  Or simply `print()` each symbol separately, since that will automatically insert a newline.

Comment: When you say "vertically", do you mean one symbol per line?

Comment: `print('\n'.join("*"*8))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def draw_symbol():
    for num in range(8):
        print("*")
    return
draw_symbol()
```

would result in:

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```